# How to prevent tag "iframe" from being deleted from the heading description of rubric?

Tags: categories, tags, html, description

I can’t insert html tag "iframe" in the description of the rubric/categories. The tag is deleted along with the content.

How to prevent tag "iframe" from being deleted from the heading description?

Comment: скриншот 1: https://priscree.ru/img/60b8bb15e10afa.jpg
скриншот 2: https://priscree.ru/img/940af935017ac1.jpg

Comment: remove_filter('pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
remove_filter('pre_term_description', 'wp_kses_data'); - this not work

Comment: Check that the user has the `unfiltered_html` capability.